# I can't get BoxLayout's setPreferredSize() method to work the way I want it to

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I think I solved my problem, but I don't know why it works this way, so I'm hoping someone can explain it to me so I don't do the same mistake again in the future.

Here's a quick example that is compilable of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class BoxLayoutTest extends JFrame
{
  public BoxLayoutTest()
  {
    setSize(400,300);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    setContentPane(mainPanel);

    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
    subPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    subPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    JLabel labelTest = new JLabel("This is a test");
    subPanel.add(labelTest);

    labelTest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
    mainPanel.add(subPanel);
    System.out.println(mainPanel.getSize());
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    BoxLayoutTest testFrame = new BoxLayoutTest();
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

At first, I had problems with the panel containing the JLabel not resizing like it should with the preferred size. I found out that it was because I was using some variation of mainPanel.getSize() as a preferred size for my subpanels. In this example, I'm using actual number values, which work.

The reason why it didn't work the old way (and that's actually the thing I'd like someone to explain), is why, as seen in the SOP line, mainPanel.getSize() returns a width and a height of 0 while it clearly takes the whole screen, which is 400x300.

Thanks @camickr for telling me I shouldn't set a preferredSize for my Panels, this helped me figure out where the problem was coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why [does] `mainPanel.getSize()` returns a width and a height of 0?

Until [`pack()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) "causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents," the dimensions will be zero.

```
System.out.println(mainPanel.getSize());
this.pack();
System.out.println(mainPanel.getSize());
```

Console:

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]
java.awt.Dimension[width=160,height=30]
```

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to say why your code doesn't work, since you didn't post your code. A few random lines of code does not give us the context of how the code is used in your program.

When you post a question you need to post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates the problem.

The glue should not have fixed the problem. The panel should still display, its just that it may not display in the position you expect it to be. A BoxLayout will attempt to resize components added to it to fill up the entire space available to it.

You should not be using setPreferredSize() on a panel. It is the job of the layout manager to calculate the preferred size of the panel based on the preferred size of all the components added to it. So I would say your code is still wrong.

> is there a difference between typing this and this.getContentPane()

Certain methods calls are automatically forwarded to the content pane of the frame, which is why the end result is the same. Read the JFrame API. This is addressed in the API description or for the method in question.

Comment: I know that I'm supposed to post a SSCCE, but I posted most (90%+) of my uncommented methods bar the variable declarations. I had the rest commented and that's how I tried to isolate the problem and post it here. The glue thing didn't actually fix it per se, but I could simulate a larger panel that way. To put this into context, this is a title bar that is supposed to take the whole width of the screen at the top. It just wraps around the JLabel, though, which is not what I want. When I change the layout to a flowLayout, everything works. Sorry if my code example wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I took your advice and removed the setPreferredSize from the JPanel and used it for the JLabel instead. It did not work. It works if I use setMaximumSize, though, which means that I don't actually understand how the preferredSize works, because I thought that the preferredSize would be the one used if the container had enough space to use it.